# Split mongoose models into subsets based on session variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, mongoose

I'm migrating an application from MySQL to Node/Mongoose running on Express. Currently in my LAMP stack I have an "account_id" column in several tables, and according to the "active account" in the session, the system automatically queries according to the account_id. Obviously I can do the same in my new setup, but seeing as I'm new to Node, Mongoose, and NoSQL in general, I was wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this with this new technology.

I was thinking:

1) Use multiple databases (but I can't figure out how to determine database from session unless I connect to the database separately on each request)

2) Add a prefix to the collection name, but then I'd have to reconstruct the mongoose.model object on every request, which I guess wouldn't be so bad.

What are the costs and benefits to these and other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to have a user model and have it be connected to the other models of your project like so:

```
mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String, 
}))

mongoose.model('Other', new Schema({
    user: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    name: String,
}))
```

It shouldn't be much different from you MySQL database.

Comment: @jraede did this help any?